# Php not accepting large json files

Tags: php, json

I am accepting the json string form another server,which is not big in size. I am accepting this by using

```
    $handle = fopen("php://input", "rb");
    $raw_post_data = '';
    while (!feof($handle)) {
        $raw_post_data .= fread($handle, 2000);
    }
    fclose($handle);
```

Problem is , if file is bigger , it does not show any thing (i checked in postman), but if string is small, it works correctly. I checked by printing the data as array. POST size and upload size is around 200MB.

Please help, with what else should i work.
Thanks

Comment: check if apache has json file size limit default smaller than 200MB, norally IIS limit the size to a few MB, but you can upscale it.

Comment: @Twocode, i talked to server guys and they said that their default size is greater than 10MB